# Proving that a sequence is cauchy in a metric space, under a specific property.

Tags: analysis, convergence-divergence, metric-spaces, cauchy-sequences

It is given that $(X,d)$ is a metric space.
Suppose that $(x_n)_{n∈\Bbb N}$ is a sequence in X with the property that
$\sum _{n=1} ^ \infty d(x_{n+1},x_n) < \infty$.  I am asked to show that the sequence is convergent.  I decided to prove this by showing that this sequence is a Cauchy sequence in X.  In other words to show that for every $\epsilon >0$ there exists $N \in \Bbb N$ such that for all n,m $\ge$N $d(x_n,x_m) < \epsilon $.

However I don't know how to start and how to use the given property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$d(x_{n+m},x_n)\leq d(x_{n+1},x_n)+...+d(x_{n+m},x_{n+m-1})$, since $\sum_nd(x_{n+1},x_n)$ finite, for every $c>0$, there exists $n_0$ such that $n>n_0$ implies that $d(x_{n+m},x_n)\leq d(x_{n+1},x_n)+...+d(x_{n+m},x_{n+m-1})<c$, thus $x_n$ is a Cauchy sequence.

Answer (score 0):

This is quite simplly done, let 
$$c=\sum_{i=1}^\infty d(x_n,x_n+1)$$
From this do we know that
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}c-\sum_{i=1}^n d(x_n,x_n+1)=0$$
which means that for any $\epsilon$ we can find an $N$ such that $n,m>N$ we have that $d(x_n,x_m)<\epsilon$

Comment: do you mean $x_{n+1} $ ? @Zelos

Comment: I mean $x_m$ as that is what is required for it to be a cauchy sequence.